# Python ctypes: initializing c_char_p()

Tags: c++, python, ctypes, shared-objects

I wrote a simple C++ program to illustrate my problem:

```
extern "C"{
    int test(int, char*);
}

int test(int i, char* var){
    if (i == 1){
        strcpy(var,"hi");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I compile this into an so.  From python I call:

```
from ctypes import *

libso = CDLL("Debug/libctypesTest.so")
func = libso.test
func.res_type = c_int

for i in xrange(5):
    charP = c_char_p('bye')
    func(i,charP)
    print charP.value
```

When I run this, my output is:

```
bye
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

I expected:

```
bye
hi
bye
bye
bye
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string which you initialized with the characters `"bye"`, and whose address you keep taking and assigning to `charP`, does not get re-initialized after the first time.

Follow the advice [here](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=c_char_p#fundamental-data-types):

> You should be careful, however, not to
>   pass them to functions expecting
>   pointers to mutable memory. If you
>   need mutable memory blocks, ctypes has
>   a create_string_buffer function which
>   creates these in various ways.

A "pointer to mutable memory" is exactly what your C function expects, and so you should use the `create_string_buffer` function to create that buffer, as the docs explain.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to charP = create_string_buffer("bye"), fixes my problem. I should have scrutinized the docs better.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing python is reusing the same buffer for all 5 passes. once you set it to "hi", you never set it back to "bye" You can do something like this:

```
extern "C"{
    int test(int, char*);
}

int test(int i, char* var){
    if (i == 1){
        strcpy(var,"hi");
    } else {
        strcpy(var, "bye");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

but be careful, `strcpy` is just asking for a buffer overflow

Comment: Good call about the strcpy and overflow, Alex's answer below should address problem as well, I'll just make sure my buffer is large enough.